# Install gazebo ros control with Gazebo 6

Tags: control, gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have installed ros indigo on my Ubuntu 14.04 and because I needed some features of Gazebo 6 I installed ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros-pkgs. I need to use gazebo ros control but there is no package ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros-control and if I try to install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control I get a message that I need to have Gazebo 2 on my system with ros indigo. How can I solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13425/install-gazebo-ros-control-with-gazebo-6/) by [pap-x](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2424/pap-x/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 50 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could build [gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing#B.InstallfromSource%28onUbuntu%29) from source.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1